# How to trigger an event 2 seconds after button is stop being clicked in woocommerce?

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

My problem now is the woocommerce cart will be auto updated after 5 seconds(start counting when user modify the quantity) even the user is still clicking the plus button..what i want is the cart will only updates when user is stop clicking after 2 secs.. This only make sense in shopping website.

```
///auto update cart after 5 seconds
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('div.woocommerce').on('click', '.minus, .plus', function(){ 
      var timeoutMinus;

      timeoutMinus = setTimeout(function(){
        $("[name='update_cart']").prop("disabled", false);  
        $("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");

      },5000);     
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On each click you need to clear timeout, than set it again this way:

```
var updateCartTimeout = null;
$('div.woocommerce').on('click', '.minus, .plus', function() {
    clearTimeout(updateCartTimeout);
    updateCartTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $("[name='update_cart']").prop("disabled", false);
        $("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Glad it does, than please mark this answer as correct one - it may help other guys with similar problem.